# How to use transform to copy file to map?

Tags: c++

My code has changed significantly, so a little update:

The exercise is to read two cpp files to count and compare a predefined list of keywords(int, bool, etc.). The goal is to learn to use the algorithm library and work with data structures beyond basic c or cpp knowledge.

The teacher advises to use transform to load keywords.txt in a map. Then read file1 and with count_if increment all the keyword values. Use count_if with file2 to decrement the values. At the end there is a check if the files are identical, nearly identical or probably different. (This is a basic example, it does not check for int* etc. It is more of a proof of concept exercise.)

I did things a little different in the end. I input the keywords to a vector and then loop through that vector, scanning file1 and file2 and comparing the value. This is slower ( (O)=m*N, so (o)=N for a small m), but only uses one vector for storage.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::istream_iterator
#include <fstream>      //fin
#include <string>       //string
#include <cmath>        //abs
#include <algorithm>    //count_if, transform
#include <vector>       //vector
using namespace std;

int keywordInit(vector<string> &keywords) {
    string s;
    istream_iterator<string> itEnd;
    ifstream fin("keywords.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open()){
        return -1;
    }
    istream_iterator<string> s_it(fin);
    vector<string>::iterator vec_it = keywords.begin();
    insert_iterator<vector<string>> insert_it (keywords,vec_it);
    copy(s_it, itEnd, insert_it);
    return keywords.size();
}

int main() {
    string s;
    int AQ = 0;
    int temp;
    vector<string> keywords;
    istream_iterator<string> itEnd;

    if (keywordInit(keywords)<1){
        cout << "Can't open keywords.txt or it is empty! Press a key to exit." << endl;
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Geef filenaam 1: ";
    cin >> s;
    ifstream finA(s); //don't check if I can open file, I know

    cout << "Geef filenaam 2: ";
    cin >> s;
    ifstream finB(s); //don't check if I can open file, I know
    for (auto& i : keywords){
        finA.clear(); finA.seekg(0);
        finB.clear(); finB.seekg(0);
        istream_iterator<string> itA(finA);
        istream_iterator<string> itB(finB);
        temp = abs(count_if(itA, itEnd, [i](string j){return j == i; }) - count_if(itB, itEnd, [i](string j){return j == i; }));
        if (temp>1){ //probably not equal, can exit
            cout << "Deze programma's zijn hoogstwaarschijnlijk wel origineel." << endl;
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
        else if (temp == 1){
            ++AQ;
        }
        if (AQ>3){ //probably not equal, can exit
            cout << "Deze programma's zijn hoogstwaarschijnlijk wel origineel." << endl;
            cin.get();
            cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (AQ){ // closely related
        cout << "Deze programma's zijn misschien niet origineel." << endl;
    }
    else{ // asume copy 
        cout << "Deze programma's zijn hoogstwaarschijnlijk niet origineel." << endl; 
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**old post:**

For my assignment I have to input a list of keywords from a textfile to a map using algorithms.

Without algorithms I have the following solution:

```
int keywordInitFind(map<string,int>* freq) {
    string s;
    int counter;
    ifstream fin("keywords.txt");
    while(fin >> s){
        if (freq->find(s) == freq->end()){
            freq->insert(pair<string,int>(s,0));
            ++counter;
            //DEBUG:
            //cout << "Read: " << s << endl;
        }
    }
    return counter; //amount of unique keywords in map
}
```

First of, I do not know how to give the arguments for begin and end of cin. Storing the whole file in another container seems a bit pointless. Secondly, I don't know what operation to use (insert?).

Comment: I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: I don't have a question anymore, but I did not really get an answer from here :/.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is `istream_iterator`. Using those, you can treat a stream as a sequence described by two iterators, as required by STL-style algorithms.

Notes:

- Your above code could have used a `std::set` instead.
- Unless it has previous content, the `freq` has the same number of elements (`freq.size()`) as is returned.
- The name suggests "frequence", but all the values of this key-value store will be zero.
- Passing in a pointer is misleading, use a C++ reference instead.
- If you actually want to count the number of occurrances, using `freq[s]++` works, as that will insert an element unless it is already present.
- You never check whether the file can be opened or not.

Comment: for the notes:
1, I am using namespace std, will that suffice?
2, counter is indeed not needed, size() will be better
3, this just initializes the container, it will be used later in the program:
`    cout << "Geef filenaam 1: ";
    cin >> w;
    ifstream finA(w.c_str());
    while (finA >> w) {
        if (freqA.find(w) != freqA.end()){
            ++freqA[w];
        }
    }`
4, jup, thanks!
5, I want to check another file for these given keywords, I think I can even remove the .find() and still satisfy the assignment
6, keywords.txt is added in the project, but a check would improve it.

Comment: To use `std::set` you need to include the according header. If you find an error after opening a file, just `throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file")`, which is the simplest default way to act on errors.